# Stop background sound when leaving the initial View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

My app has looped background music that plays over the initial view controller.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/bgMusic.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

    NSError *error;
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
        [audioPlayer play];
}
```

When leaving the initial view controller I want the music to stop, so I used the code below, but instead it restarts.

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [audioPlayer stop];
}
```

Comment: try to set audioPlayer = nil after [audioPlayer stop];

Comment: Read Documentation here:https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/HandlingAudioInterruptions/HandlingAudioInterruptions.html

Comment: What is `audioPlayer`? Where does it come from? Is it a global var? What is the value of `audioPlayer` in `-viewWillDisappear`?

Comment: @Gagan_iOS didn't work :(

Comment: make the `self.audioPlayer = nil;` in `viewDidUnload`

Comment: Works for me. Just built a test app, no issues. Try putting an NSLog in your viewDidLoad and viewWillDisappear to make sure that what you are putting on top of the view is actually calling viewWillDisappear...and also to see if your base controller is being re-instantiated.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad Sorry I'm really new at this, don't understand all your questions. I set up an AVAudioPlayer like this: `code`{AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;}

Comment: The identifier `audioPlayer` has to be declared at some location in your source code. Where is it? The snippet shows the usage of it only.

Comment: please show your code after adding nil

Comment: @MikeCritchley. I just made a test app myself and there it worked for me also. Can't understand what it is in my real project that screw things up!? In the viewDidLoad, below my background music-code, I have 16 other music files called from 16 different AVAudioPlayer (this is probably weird not the right way to do it ;). Then after that I have the viewWillDisappear (in which I stop all my 17 music files so they won't continue playing when leaving the view. It works on the other 16, but they are played by pressing buttons).

Comment: @PraveenKumar `viewDidUnload` hasn't been used since iOS 6.

Comment: Could this have to do with class? I set up another View Controller, and when I push to that one the music stops. It has the class "UIViewController", while the other one has the class "ViewController" (in order to set up actions and outlets). @MikeCritchley

Comment: Wow. So you have 17 individual instances of an AVAudioPlayer? Yeah, there's probably a better way to do that lol As for the viewController thing, it's all  the same. In your .m file, you'll see ViewController -- which is the default name given if you're using a template. But if you check the .h file, you should always see <ViewControllerName> : UIViewController -- so the UIViewController is the super class and the named ViewController is the subclass. So that shouldn't be causing issues. Hard to say without seeing more of the code.

Comment: Ok, but when I change the new View Controller to "ViewController" the music keeps playing again. Stackoverflow won't let me post more code, but made en image and uploaded here: http://tippytap.se/onewebmedia/kod.jpg (deleted som repetitive code). @MikeCritchley